# Qtablewidget Throwing Segmentation Fault

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qtablewidget, ros

I am using QtableWidget to populate data collected from ROS messages:

```
ui->stat->setColumnCount(3);
    //ui->stat->setRowCount(5);
    count_row=0;// keep track of table rows
    ui->stat->setColumnWidth(0,145);
    ui->stat->setColumnWidth(1,50);
    ui->stat->setColumnWidth(2,300);
QStringlist labels;
    labels.push_back(" Time");
    labels.push_back("Type");
    labels.push_back("Message ");
    ui->stat->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);
QTableWidgetItem* text = new QTableWidgetItem();
       QTableWidgetItem* msgType = new QTableWidgetItem();
       QTableWidgetItem* time = new QTableWidgetItem();
count_row=count_row%5;
ui->stat->setItem(count_row,0,time);
      ui->stat->setItem(count_row,1,msgType);
      ui->stat->setItem(count_row,2,text);
      count_row++;
      for(int i=4;i>=0;i--)
           ui->stat->showRow(i);
```

On running the program, I am getting segmentation fault error

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash. Is a back trace available?

Answer (score 0):

in order to use `setItem(row, col, text)` you need to set number of rows (this line: `//ui->stat->setRowCount(5);`) or, if you do not know how many rows you'll have, you can use
`insertRow(count_row)` and after that set items for that row.